# How Play Framework handle CloseEvent from WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

I am using Play Framework with WebSocket in Scala, and I try to accept with Actor.

If web server close the connection, the client can touch this by `onClose` in JS like this:

```
websocket.onclose = function (evt) { onClose(evt) };
```

But what about the server side?

If the client close the browser, can web server touch this close event?

Comment: Websocket actor is stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def ws(userId: String) =
WebSocket.tryAcceptWithActor[String, String](request⇒
  Future {
    Right(out ⇒ Props(new WsActor(userId, out)))
  })
class WsActor(val userId: String, val clientActor: ActorRef) extends Actor{
  override def receive: Receive = ???

  @throws[Exception](classOf[Exception])
  override def preStart(): Unit = {

  }
    //when client close 
    //will call it 
  @throws[Exception](classOf[Exception])
  override def postStop(): Unit = {
    println("stop")
  }

}
```

Comment: Hello. How to get actorRef in postStop, because I am using actorRef as an Identifier in a HashMap of connected clients, and on disconnect I want remove the entry from HashMap.